# While - Retorna um registro

Tags: php

Tenho um WebService que me retorna alguns dados como, extrato, saldo etc...

Más quando mando exibir o extrato ele me retorna apenas o primeiro registro, não todos. E fica repetindo sempre o 1º registro.

```
<?php
session_start();
$cartao = $_SESSION['cartao'];
?>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />    
<?php

require_once 'vale-consulta.php';

try {

    $dados = array(
        'cd_grupo'        => '38',
        'de_login_usu'    => 'loginusuario',
        'de_senha_usu'    => 'senhapassword',
        'nu_cartao'       => $cartao,
        'fl_apenas_saldo' => 'N'
    );

    $vale = new ValeConsulta();
    $resposta = $vale->consultar( $dados );

    if ( $vale->tem_erro() ) {
        echo "Código: " . $resposta->erro->cod . "<br >\n";
        echo "MSG: " . $resposta->erro->msg . "<br >\n";
    } else {

        $nick         = $resposta->nome;
        $nome       = explode(" ", $nick);
        $saldo         = $resposta->vl_saldo;
        $ldata         = $resposta->lancamentos->lancto->dt_lancto;
        $ldesc      = $resposta->lancamentos->lancto->descricao;
        $lvalor       = $resposta->lancamentos->lancto->valor;
        $extrato    = $ldesc."</br>".$ldata."</br>".$lvalor."</br>";
    }

} catch( SoapFault $fault ) {
    echo "Erro: " . $fault->faultcode . " - " . $fault->faultstring;
}
?>
```

While

```
<?php
include("mostra.php")
//mostra extrato

$i = 1;
    while($i < 5) {
            echo $extrato; 
            $++;
        }
?>
```

Me retornando

```
Lucas SOBRE NOME MEU //MEU NOME COMPLETO
124                  //SALDO
KIDELICIA            //EXTRATO NOME DA EMPRESA
07/09/2016           //DATA EXTRATO
10,50 D              //VALOR NO DEBIDO
```

[PDF AQUI](https://www.sendspace.com/file/l4pefl)

Comment: Coloque um trecho mais significativo de código. Como está sendo mostrado $extrato sempre vai ter o mesmo valor mesmo, só o índice que está sendo incrementado.

Comment: @gmsantos , sou novo em PHP amigo ainda não sei todas funções! como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Lucas, não sei como posso te ajudar, tente [edit] sua pergunta e deixar mais claro qual sua dúvida. Leitura recomentada: [tour] e [mcve]

Comment: Você precisa colocar todo o código necessário para que seja possível fazer um mínimo de análise do problema, de qualquer forma, já adianto que se você está utilizando um webservice, você provavelmente não sabe a quantidade de registros que ele irá retornar, por isso você não deve usar o comando WHILE (ao menos não com valor fixo) e sim usar um FOREACH, que atende melhor essa necessidade.

Comment: @KennyRafael dei uma editada, onde encontro docs desse FOREACH ? para fazer isso!

Comment: Posta o resultado do metodo `$vale->consultar( $dados );` pois ele dever retornar um array com os resultados, ai você vai fazer um `for` na variavel `$resposta` e assim listar tudo.

Comment: @NeuberOliveira segue a edição, oque me retorna e o PDF do webservice

Comment: @LucasBicalleto pode usar o manual do PHP, online, http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: @stderr bem observado, foi apenas um erro de digitação. pois estava simulando oque estou fazendo!

Comment: @LucasBicalleto pode complementar a resposta com o que é escrito na tela quando vc executa esse comando echo var_dump($resposta);

Comment: coloca isso em baixo do     $resposta = $vale->consultar( $dados );

Comment: @HiagoSouza funcionou, agora como exibo isso ordenado pois está assim : http://pt-br.tinypic.com/r/ifbqfs/9

Comment: coloca isso echo '<pre>';print_r($resposta);echo '</pre>'; por favor para eu ver a estrutura no lugar do echo var_dump...

Comment: ai depois reencaminhe o print.

Comment: @HiagoSouza http://pt-br.tinypic.com/r/9q9or6/9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está recuperando um XML tente percorrer o vetor como abaixo.

```
$resposta = $vale->consultar( $dados );
foreach($resposta->lancamentos->lancto as $info) {

    echo $info->dt_lancto . " - " . $info->descricao . " - " . info->valor;

}
```

Comment: Perfeito, muito obrigado @Hiago Souza e a todos que contribuirão!